# How is the String in a main method refer to someText in another method?

Tags: java

I am trying to first output a String of like this:

`Hello -`

then I need that for example if I write, Jane it would output:

`Hello -  - Jane -`

is this code correct? If not, what did I do wrong and what does this code actually do?

Thank you

```
public class myClass { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
     String a = new String("Hello"); 
     addHyphen(a); 
     System.out.println(a); 
} 


public static void addHyphen(String someText) { 
   someText = "-" + someText + "-"; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Your function does not take any input, so where will you input "Jane"? Presently, `addHyphen()` will simply return `-Hello-`

Comment: oh I see so I would need only to simply ask the user to enter?

Comment: I've updated my answer @ppc, make sure to add those changes to your code when running it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print out a space, followed by a hyphen after the passed string in `addHyphen()`, then you can do something like this:

```java
public static String addHyphen(String someText) { 
    return someText + " -"; 
}
```

Also, note that this function returns back a String, so you need to change your code in `main()`:

```java
String a = new String("Hello");  
System.out.println(addHyphen(a));
```

This simply returns the string back, with an appended hyphen to the calling function.

**NOTE**: If you want to enter the string as input, then you need to use the `Scanner` class. Code to get a String object input would be:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(“Input a String:”);
String str = scan.nextLine();
```

Note that you need to import `java.util.Scanner` for using the `Scanner` class

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking something like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "Hello"; 
     addHyphen(a); 
    }

   public static void addHyphen(String someText) { 
   someText = "-" + someText + "-"; 
   System.out.println(someText); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `someText` argument is scoped to the `addHyphen` method; the assignment you are doing is not visible outside the method. You can change the method to return a `String` and then assign that result to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to study [Scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/), `sometext` can't retain its value. It will have always `new` value whenever its `called`. Either you ave to change the `scope` of the variables or you can do something like this:

```
public class myClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String a = "Hello"; 
        String b = "Jane";
        System.out.println( addHyphen(a));
        System.out.println( addHyphen(a)+ addHyphen(b)); 
    }

    public static String addHyphen(String someText) 
    { 
        return  " -" + someText + "-"; 
    } 
}
```